# Replace line feed with a character

Tags: bash, echo

I want to replace **\n** with a character.

```
echo -n  "s\n" |tr  "\n"  "a"
s\n
```

Why can't get  **sa** as result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `man echo`:

> `-e` enable interpretation of backslash escapes

Your echo may be a shell builtin (try `type echo`). If so, use `help echo` instead of `man echo`. But it should say the same about `-e` option.

**Without this option the `\n` string is printed literally, not as a line feed.** Notice `tr` needs no special option to work as you expect.

Fixed command:

```
echo -ne  "s\n" | tr  "\n"  "a"
```

---

Fellow user Gordon Davisson pointed out some things. They seem important enough to include them in my answer for future reference. From this point all credit goes to [Gordon](https://superuser.com/users/7778/gordon-davisson).

> Different versions of `echo` are very inconsistent with respect to escapes and options. Some will interpret escape sequences without `-e`. Some will print "-e" as part of their output. Some do… other things. For things like this, use `printf` instead (as in `printf "s\n"`). See the [POSIX spec for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html), especially the "application usage" section.

Comment: Different versions of `echo` are very inconsistent wrt escapes and options. Some will interpret escape sequences without `-e`. Some will print "-e" as part of their output. Some do... other things. For things like this, use `printf` instead (as in `printf "s\n"`). See the [POSIX spec for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html), especially the "application usage" section.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thank you. I have cited your comment in my answer.